# Why doesn't Ubuntu run after installing?

Tags: boot, partitioning, hardware, bios, usb-installation

Today I've tried to install Ubuntu using my bootable usb drive from windows 10 education. 
I selected installation type as 'Something Else' and removed my hard drive where my previous os was placed. After pressing 'install now', I got a message to make "EFI System Partition" then I have allocated 500mb for that and press install now. I selected /dev/sda1 for installing Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS. It said that successfully installed. But when it completed and I reboot my pc then my ubuntu installation bar back again and it says to install ubuntu again. After unpluged my usb a message shows in black screen.

this product is covered by one or more of the following patents

I have checked and my hardwares, motherboard are fine. I have tried again to reinstall ubuntu then it shows an existing Ubuntu already in there. What can I do now?

EDIT: output of `sudo parted -l`:

[image]

Comment: There was no need to remove Windows drive. Boot into Live Ubuntu, then run command `sudo parted -l` and post output.

Comment: here is the output of "sudo parted -l" @PaulBenson 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1mC3Y8E-2BFYdk07K2rkfM-ufxVDgKRej/view?usp=sharing

Comment: OK. I would start again with Ubuntu from scratch. You currently have an MBR disk that needs converting to GPT. You  will lose everything on it when you do this. From Live USB, run Gparted. Select Ubuntu disk, (currently sda), then `device`, then choose GPT and wait for conversion to finish. Then re-install Ubuntu, but connect your Windows disk first. **Make sure you don't overwrite Windows** when you re-install. No need to make an ESP partition as this will be done automatically.

Comment: Will everything be done automatically if I select "Erase data and install ubuntu"? @PaulBenson

Comment: I suggest you do as mentioned. By converting your Ubuntu drive to GPT everything will be erased including partitions. Just be sure once you connect your Windows disk, that you **convert the correct disk** to install Ubuntu on. Although It shows as sda now, it may change to sdb when Windows disk is connected. Just make a primary root partition (eg 60GB) for Ubuntu and leave some unallocated space after it.. Swap and Home partitions aren't really necessary but you can add them if you want. – Paul Benson 23 mins ago

Comment: Thanks for your co-operation. Everything is running perfectly now. ❤ @PaulBenson